# Finding the best fit for a given data and the best guess values when fitting a given equation

Tags: fitting

If I have the following data

```
Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/1XhEEJCr", "Package"]
```

Which gives the following Figure:

[image: Figure]

I have two questions:

### Question 1

Is there any way that Mathematica with a code can tell you what is the best fit for this data and give the parameters?.

### Question 2

If I wanted to fit this data let's say to the following equation:

```
r10 E^(-((r00 - x)/r20)) r20^-r30 (r00 - x)^(-1 + r30)
```

where I am using the following code

```
NonlinearModelFit[data,r10 E^(-((r00 - x)/r20)) r20^-r30 (r00 - x)^(-1 + r30), {{r10,0.62}, {r20, 0.5}, {r30, 22}}, x];
```

Is there any way to ask Mathematica or to know what would be the best guesses for this or any data?.

For this case the guess values for `r10`,`r20` and `r30` are not correct and I am not sure how I will go about finding the best guess to try to fit this data to that equation and see if that fits or not.

Thank you

Comment: 1) No: a sensible model must come from the physical meaning of the data; No algorithm can do that reliably. 2) Not really; in fact, a good choice of initial values is often the most difficult yet important choice in fitting data sensibly.

Comment: Question 2): You could  use `NonlinearModelFit` without starting values: `NonlinearModelFit[data,r10 E^(-((r00 - x)/r20)) r20^-r30 (r00 - x)^(-1 + 
    r30), {r10 , r20 , r30 }, Method -> "NMinimize"]` . By the way, are you sure about your modelfunction? I would expect the exponential term to be `Exp[- (r00-x)^2 …]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks! The model of question 2 seem to fit other curves that are similar to the one posted. The model was suggested by JimB here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221229/find-best-equation-for-data-and-the-area-under-curve

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am using the code as `NonlinearModelFit[data, r10 E^(-((r00 - x)/r20)) r20^-r30 (r00 - x)^(-1 + r30), {r10, r20, r30}, Method -> "NMinimize",x]` but it does not fit the data. Is the syntaxis correct?

Comment: @John Try `NonlinearModelFit[…,x,Method->"NMinimize"]`

Comment: @John Your yellow-plot shows something like a bell curve, that 's why I would expect a squared exponent `Exp[- (r00-x)^2 …]` in your model! Unfortunately I cannot excess your data...